# Can JCS be considered an In-Process Cache or a Distributed Cache Or Both?

Tags: caching, distributed-caching, distributed-cache, jcs

Can JCS Cache run in a separate JVM Process from the client process? Any links or example will be helpful.

Comment: Moderator..plz dont delete...and let me know the issue since u deleted one i asked earlier

Comment: As for `could`, you could always write your own server around it.